# SQL Server insert error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a database and i created the following fields that are connected to each other :

```
CREATE TABLE abonat(COD_ABONAT int PRIMARY KEY ,Nume nvarchar(30),Prenume nvarchar(30),Adresa nvarchar(60),telefon char(13),CNP char(14),COD_ABONAMENT int)
CREATE TABLE abonament(COD_ABONAMENT int PRIMARY KEY,Denumire nvarchar(30),tip int,TRAFIC_MB int, PRET float, PRET_EXTRA_TRAFIC float)
CREATE TABLE contractx(NR_CONTRACT int PRIMARY KEY, COD_ABONAT int, VALABILITATE date, DATA_INCHEIERII date)
CREATE TABLE stare(NR_CONTRACT int, SERIE_MODEM char(10), STARE int)
CREATE TABLE plata(NR_FACTURA int PRIMARY KEY, DATA_PLATII date)
CREATE TABLE factura(NR_FACTURA int, COD_ABONAT int PRIMARY KEY, DATA_EMITERII date, DATA_LIMITA date, TOTAL_PLATA float)
CREATE TABLE tip(TIP_CONTRACT int PRIMARY KEY, DESCRIERE nvarchar(50), SUMA float)
CREATE TABLE penalizare(NR_FACTURA int PRIMARY KEY, SUMA float)
CREATE TABLE bonus (FACTURA int PRIMARY KEY, BONUS_TRAFIC int, BONUS_ABONAMENT float)

ALTER TABLE abonament ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CODY FOREIGN KEY (COD_ABONAMENT) REFERENCES abonat(COD_ABONAT)
ALTER TABLE contractx ADD CONSTRAINT FF_COD FOREIGN KEY (COD_ABONAT) REFERENCES abonat(COD_ABONAT)
ALTER TABLE stare ADD CONSTRAINT FF_NEWCOD FOREIGN KEY (NR_CONTRACT) REFERENCES contractx(NR_CONTRACT)
ALTER TABLE factura ADD CONSTRAINT FF_PLATA FOREIGN KEY (NR_FACTURA) REFERENCES plata(NR_FACTURA)
ALTER TABLE contractx ADD CONSTRAINT FF_ALTELE FOREIGN KEY (COD_ABONAT) REFERENCES factura(COD_ABONAT)

INSERT INTO abonat 
VALUES (1,'STROE','ALIN','Str. Deznatui Bloc A 15 sc 2','0741966242','1800929160031',1)
INSERT INTO abonat 
VALUES (2,'STAMIN','SILVIAN','Str. Raului nr 20','0741563241','1730229160021',2)
INSERT INTO abonat 
VALUES (3,'JIPA','ALINA','Str.Caracal nr 23','0731226120','2770929160031',3)
INSERT INTO abonat 
VALUES (4,'ROHOD','RARES','Str.Burebista nr 44','0735411469','1550520160035',4)
INSERT INTO abonat 
VALUES (5,'AMORARITEI','EUGEN','Str.Privdor Bl B3 sc 2 ap 8','0765511444','18012245160029',5)


INSERT INTO abonament
VALUES (1,'BASIC',1,500,9.99,1)
```

My problem is that when i try to insert into abonament i recieve the following error :

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CODY". The conflict occurred in database "ICSx", table "dbo.abonat", column 'COD_ABONAT'.

How can i fix this ? Is there a way i can connect the tables without having this error ?

Comment: I have ran this exact code and it works fine for me using SQL 2K8

Comment: You should probably have look at the relation between `abonat` and `abonament`. Currently you have 1:1 relationship. Is that what you want it to be? BTW, the code you have here does not give any errors.

Comment: I receive that error i don't know what i am doing wrong...

Comment: You have created a foreign key FK_CODY between two primary keys abonament.COD_ABONAMENT and abonat.COD_ABONAT, it's unusual. Is this your goal?

Comment: @opc0de Are you sure that this is all of your script? I'm struggling to understand how it works for me but not for you. There must be something else that you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird one. Are you running this on a database that has replication enabled?

Answer (score -2):

Your issue is that your statement did not insert in the last column. Count the number of columns and the number of values you specified.

I personally believe that indentation and notation and making things explicit is a good practice that can save you time. Below is how I do it.

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(
   COL1
  ,COL2
  ,COL3
)VALUES(
   1 --COL1
  ,2 --COL2
  ,3 --COL3
);
```

Comment: if i made a mistake in number of colons then i will get the error Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.